# Apple Production Push Notification certificate do not connect after new app version

Tags: php, ios, iphone, ssl, apple-push-notifications

After We uploaded new version of app on App store, apple push notification certificate for production mode stopped connecting with apple server.

I created new certificate on apple developer account and it started working. Again when we uploaded new version of the app, it stopped connecting with apple server.

Is it default behavior for IOS or I am doing something wrong?

I am using PHP for sending push notification.

Comment: Are you sure you are not creating new Distribution Provisioning Profiles each time?

Comment: No. I am using same provisioning profile. I do not change that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, if you have used that same distribution certificate then some how in your compatibility section the push notifications entitlement hasn't connected​, i have the same situation once, it was showing check mark, but i turn that off and again on then it asks me to select the profile, i did as option populated, and it works, i hadn't created the new certificate again, i use php too for push notification . So you have to make sure before uploading your app.
Thanks